# React onClick property not firing

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, onclick

I am trying to implement a simple component (an animated hamburger menu button). Its class needs to be updated when it is active or not. For that point, I'm using a state hook.
I want to add a onClick property to this button to invert its state. But this onClick function is never firing.
When I set the button active by myself, the button appearence changes as I wanted.
I am using fullPage.js in my project.

I saw a lot of topic about that, but no one answered to my problem...

Thanks for future answers !

Here is my code :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './hamburger.css';

const MenuButton = () => {
  const [isMenuActive, setIsMenuActive] = useState(false);

  return (
    <button className={`hamburger hamburger--slider ${isMenuActive && "is-active"}`} type="button" onClick={() => setIsMenuActive(!isMenuActive)}>
      <span className="hamburger-box">
        <span className="hamburger-inner"></span>
      </span>
    </button>
  );
};

export default MenuButton;
``
```

Comment: can you provide a snippet of your code ? From what I can see it's supposed to work here

Comment: I was copying my code on StackBlitz to share it to you, but on StackBlitz it works well... I don't understand.
So I think it will be useless but here is the link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zvygna?file=src/MenuButton.js

Comment: Maybe there is another component that might catch your onClick before the button catch it, did you try your button in an empty view in your real project ?

Comment: I forgot to precise a big point : I am using fullPage.js in my project. When I comment out the full page wrapper, my button works ! fullPage seems to be the problem source...

Answer (score 0):

You are starting the state with false value. So it's not firing the onClick event because it's inactive from the get go

change the initial state `useState(true)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but there is no link with that. The button is just rendered with its active from, but the problem is still the same : nothing happens when I click on it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem.

I didn't noticed that I was using React v17 (beta). I downgraded to React 16 and my button works well !